# what frequencies are used for wireless remote control of hearing aids?

Tags: remote-control

I have a pair of hearing aids which can be toggled between listening modes (telephone, noisy room, outdoors, etc.) using a key fob-like device. The control fob was lost before I got the aids, so I could not take it apart for study. However, each of the hearing aids has a pushbutton on it which lets you manually toggle the modes- and as if by magic, when you toggle one of the aids, the other one wirelessly switches modes as well so both aids are always operating in the same mode.

Does anyone know what frequencies are allocated for this application? Unfortunately I do not have an RF signal analyzer with which I could tune in to the aids while they are signaling each other to switch modes.

Comment: I believe this sort of thing would use the bands around 433MHz, 868MHz, or 2.4GHz. It might be something proprietary, though, are you sure it's not simply using bluetooth (BLE)? that would be 2.4GHz

Comment: If the device has an FCC ID printed on it, you can look it up in the FCC database and the frequency should be listed.